# Where I made a mistake in creating A* pathfind focused on wikipedia pseudocode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to learn how to use a A* path find algorithm in Unity C#. I know that solutions can be found on the Internet, only they are written in such a way that for me it is not clear.

I decided to write from scratch myself, focusing on pseudocode from wikipedia. (need to learn write any algorithm focusing on pseudocode)

I write all code in 1 script with 131 rows, which contains class Node, Method which find path, method which create array and fill neighbors, and method OnGizmosDraw which draw array, and path.
I want to know, where was I wrong, and why.

I use for i < 50 instead while, to avoid cases with unlimited iterates.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Node
{
public Vector2 thisNode;

public float gScore = 9999;
public float fScore = 9999;
public float h;

public List<Node> neighbors = new List<Node>();
}

public class AStarAlgorithm : MonoBehaviour
{
List<Node> matrix = new List<Node>();
List<Node> path = new List<Node>();

private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            Node node = new Node();
            node.thisNode = new Vector2(i, j);
            matrix.Add(node);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count; i++)
    {
        if(i < matrix.Count - 1)
            matrix[i].neighbors.Add(matrix[i + 1]);
        if (i > 0)
            matrix[i].neighbors.Add(matrix[i - 1]);
        if (i < matrix.Count - 4)
            matrix[i].neighbors.Add(matrix[i + 4]);
        if (i > 3)
            matrix[i].neighbors.Add(matrix[i - 4]);
    }

    path = AStar(matrix[0], matrix[15], 0);
}

private List<Node> AStar(Node start, Node goal, int h)
{
    List<Node> openSet = matrix;
    List<Node> closeSet = new List<Node>();
    List<Node> cameFrom = new List<Node>();

    openSet[0].gScore = 0;
    openSet[0].fScore = h;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if (openSet.Count > 0)
        {
            Node node = openSet[GetLowerFScore(openSet)];

            if (node == goal)
            {
                return cameFrom;
            }

            openSet.Remove(node);
            closeSet.Add(node);

            foreach (Node neighbor in node.neighbors)
            {
                if (closeSet.Contains(node))
                    continue;

                float tentative_gScore = node.gScore + Vector2.Distance(node.thisNode, neighbor.thisNode);

                if (!openSet.Contains(neighbor))
                    openSet.Add(neighbor);

                if (tentative_gScore < neighbor.gScore)
                {
                    cameFrom.Add(node);
                    neighbor.gScore = tentative_gScore;
                    neighbor.fScore = neighbor.gScore + neighbor.h;

                    Debug.Log(cameFrom.Count);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Debug.Log(matrix.Count);

    return cameFrom;
}

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.gray;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(matrix[i].thisNode, matrix[i + 1].thisNode);
    }

    Gizmos.color = Color.green;

    for (int i = 0; i < path.Count - 1;i++)
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(path[i].thisNode, path[i + 1].thisNode);
    }
}

private int GetLowerFScore(List<Node> openSet)
{
    int index = -1;
    float fScore = Mathf.Infinity;

    for(int i = 0; i < openSet.Count; i++)
    {
        if(openSet[i].fScore < fScore)
        {
            index = i;
            fScore = openSet[i].fScore;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
}
```

Errors not found, but path return 0 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your implementation, so the following is definitely not an exhaustive list. Just the things that immediately jumped out at me:

1. You've passed a start node into your AStar method, but you're not using it anywhere.
2. The openSet ought to be initialized with a single element - the start node - but you've set it to the entire graph instead.
3. In a traditional A* implementation, h is not a variable that gets passed in. It's a heuristic function (typically just euclidean distance) that has a different value for any given node.
4. Your open list ought to be implemented as a priority queue instead of a plain List, or the performance of your algorithm will be really, really bad. Right now you're doing an O(N) search on the open list at every single iteration to find the next node to explore.